# What OracleCommand.BindByName = True means exactly?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

NET application and trying  update a database table. Will the below update query work? If I set BindByName = True will .NET consider null and SYSDATE as parameters as well? P.S this is shortened query and the actual query is a bit complex and so wanted some confirmation before i try it out

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TBL_xxx_xxx SET NEXT=null, ACTIONDATE=SYSDATE, comments=:pcomments, STATUS=11 WHERE ACTIONDATE IS NULL AND WFID=:pwid AND ACTIONBY=:pactionby"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.BindByName = True

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pcomments", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = somevalue
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pwid", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = somevalue
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pactionby", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = somevalue

cmd.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 10):

The opposite of `cmd.BindByName = True` is "Bind by position"

You add parameters `pcomments`, `pwid` and `pactionby`. When you set `cmd.BindByName = True` then you can add them in any order.

So, in your case this one should work as well:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pwid", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = somevalue
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pactionby", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = somevalue
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pcomments", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = somevalue
```

If you set `cmd.BindByName = False` (which is the default) then you must add the parameter in the same order as they appear in your CommandText.

Regarding your second question, either use

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TBL_xxx_xxx SET NEXT=null, ACTIONDATE=SYSDATE"
cmd.ExecuteQuery()
```

or

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TBL_xxx_xxx SET NEXT= :next, ACTIONDATE= :actDate"
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":next", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = DBNull.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":actDate", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = CType(DateTime.Now, Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate)

cmd.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Hi Wernfried. 

Thanks for your reply......will next=null and action=sysdate create any issues? will the values for next and action update as normal?